# char[N] versus char *

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Could anyone tell me why there is a compile error with the following code?

```
struct Foo {
  char m_p[8];
  inline operator char *() const { return m_p; }
};
```

With GCC 4.5 I am given the message:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const
>   char*' to 'char*'

while the Digital Mars compiler has no problem with it.

Edit: The answers listed below mention the const qualifier on the function. What I really don't get then is why the following code has no such problem:

```
struct Foo2 {
  char *m_p;
  inline operator char *() const { return m_p; }
};
```

Comment: That seems fine as-is. I think the context of this is what's important to see here.

Comment: Well, the error message you got from the compiler is self-explanatory. You have a `const char[8]` array, which can be converted to `const char *` pointer, but not to `char *` pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since that operator is a `const` function, `this` and all its members (`m_p`) is supposed to be const. So the type of `m_p` is `const char[8]`. It cannot be implicitly converted to `char*` as the `const`-ness will be lost. Conversion to `const char*` is OK.

You could either make it return a `const char*`

```
 inline operator const char *() const { return m_p; }
```

or remove the `const` qualifier

```
 inline operator char *() { return m_p; }
```

or provide both methods.

Digital Mars is wrong here. Or maybe you need to enable some warnings.

Comment: Thanks KennyTM. What I don't yet get is why a `char *` instead of a `char [N]` gives no error, even with the `const` on the conversion operator.

Comment: When you change it to a pointer, the `const` qualification on the member function applies only to the pointer itself (as a member of the class), not the object(s) that is points to. So `m_p` is of type `char * const`, which can be converted to `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Because within the function (being const-qualified) the type of your array is `const char[8]`, and that can't be converted to `char*`, only `const char*`.

Either ditch the const-qualification on the function, or add it to the return type. Also, `inline` is redundan here, because members defined within the class definition are implicitly `inline` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between char m_p[8] and char *m_p is that the former is a part of your object and when accessed from const qualified method it will become const. For the pointer it points somewhere else and you can return it from const qualified method without forcing it to be const.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator is marked as `const`, so it gets a `const` `this` pointer. This means that whatever field of the `struct` you'll try to access via that `this` pointer will actually be `const` (because it's being accessed through a `const`-path), so when you do `return m_p;` `m_p` decays to a `const char *`, which in turn cannot be converted to `char *` (the return type of the operator), because dropping the `const` modifier requires a `const_cast`.

Long story short: if you want that operator to be `const`, then the return type must be `const char *`, otherwise you'd have a situation where a `const` method (=>which can be called on a `const` object) would be able to let the caller modify the object (via the non-`const` pointer returned) even if this should be forbidden by the `const`.